# Unregister listeners when calling map.removeControl

Tags: openlayers, javascript, events

I use [ol-ext Profile tool](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.control.Profil.html) to display profiles along vector lines.

When I call

```
map.removeControl(profil);
profil = null;
```

to remove the profil, the listeners associated with the tool remain registered, causing errors since the object does not exists anymore.

Is `removeControl` supposed to unregister all listeners associated with the tool, or should this be handled by the ol-ext control itself?

Comment: Are you talking about listeners you defined/created?

Comment: Not me, but these listeners are defined/created in the constructor of ol-ext Profile tools (https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/master/src/control/Profile.js). I guess ol-ext Profile tool should be responsible for unregistering these, but I wondered if there was a special procedure for that.

Comment: I tried removing control with official example ftom http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.profile.html, but I'm getting no error after control removal.

Comment: Even if setting profil = null; or replacing profil by a new one?

Comment: I only tried removing control and setting `profil = null;`. See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/7oug3Lvh/. After 5 seconds control is removed but there are not errors in the console later.